# Dynamic Component OutputField Bound to SObject

Tags: dynamic-visualforce, dynamic-binding

I am trying to bind a field to an outputfield dynamically apex, but in doing so I get

> value for `<apex:outputField>` is not a dynamic binding!

This does not work:

```
        Component.Apex.OutputField field = new Component.Apex.OutputField();
        string cndField = 'Custom_Field__c'; 
        field.value = cand.get(cndField);     //problem
        candidateComponentPanel.childComponents.add(field);
```

I believe trying to do this dynamically with the "cand" being an SObject is causing an issue.

For reference, doing it with outputtext works fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add : {!}, it should work be :

```
field.value = '{!'+cand.get(cndField)+'}';
```

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

`apex:outputField`'s value takes an expression not any static value.

So you will have to provide an expression to it and since the field api is also dynamic, you will have to use string concatenation inside the expression, like this.

```
Component.Apex.OutputField field = new Component.Apex.OutputField();
string cndField = 'Custom_Field__c'; 
field.expressions.value = '{!cand.'+cndField+'}';     //notice the field.expressions.value and the string I provided will render to {!cand.Custom_Field__c}
candidateComponentPanel.childComponents.add(field);
```